# Record multiple audio files and merge (append) them into one

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I'm creating an app in which the user has to be able to record speech and listen to this recording. But after listening the user has to be able to continue recording resulting in one file with all recordings merged into (all of them appended to the first one).

I noticed from searching some SO answers that merging two audio files is easiest when they are recorded in the WAV format (if an other format is possible that's fine too). So I searched for a way to record in the WAV format and found the [ExtAudioRecorder class](http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording).

Using this class I successfully recorded .amr files with good audio quality (this is a compressed format). But when I try to record in the .wav format I get a choppy version of the thing(s) I said whilst recording (it sounds like the recorder/player is skipping parts) very much like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499351/blank-gaps-appears-when-recording-audio-with-audiorecord).

When the app is recording and I press the stop button it takes some time before the app responds (only when the recording is in WAV/uncompressed), compressed recordings work perfect (apart from the merging). This leads me to believe that the recording is done on the UI thread.

This is my code (in the record Fragment):

```
private boolean createRecorder() {
    try {
        recorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(false);
        recorder.setOutputFile(recordingFile);
        recorder.prepare();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean createPlayer() {
    if (recordingFile != null) {
        try {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(recordingFile);
            player.prepare();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
    return false;
}

private void recordButtonPressed() {
    if (pageState == State.Recording) { 
        return;
    } else if (pageState == State.Playing) {
        this.pauseButtonPressed();
    }

    if (this.createRecorder()) {
        recorder.start();
        pageState = State.Recording;
    }
}

private void pauseButtonPressed() { //works as a stop button
    if (pageState == State.Recording) {
        this.destroyRecorder();
        pageState = State.Idle;


    } else if (pageState == State.Playing) {
        this.destroyPlayer();
        pageState = State.Idle;
    }
}

private void playButtonPressed() {
    if (pageState == State.Playing) { 
        return;
    } else if (pageState == State.Recording) {
        this.pauseButtonPressed();
    }

    if (this.createPlayer()) {
        player.start();
        pageState = State.Playing;
    }
}
```

My ExtAudioRecorder class is the exact same as [the original](http://i-liger.com/sites/default/files/ExtAudioRecorder.java).

I'm looking for an answer on one of the following questions (with the emphasis on the first):

1. How can I get my app to record without the choppiness/UI freezing?
2. How can I merge two compressed .amr files into one?
3. Is there any other way to do what I'm trying to achieve (described in the first paragraph) and how should I go about doing this?

Comment: The standard `AudioRecord` API will give you uncompressed PCM which you can easily concatenate. As for merging two .amr files, if they're raw AMR files (i.e. not put in a container like 3GP) it should just be  matter of skipping the first 6 bytes of the second file, and concatenating the rest to the first file.

Comment: The `ExtAudioRecorder` is using the AudioRecord lib but it gives me the choppy audio files for some reason. The AMR files are compressed. Do you have any tutorial/example I can follow because I have been working on this for almost two weeks and still have the same issues.